# how to prevent list hiding under tabbar in SliverPersistentHeader in flutter?

Tags: flutter, tabbar, customscrollview

I'm making tiktok clone flutter app

now i'm on profile screen

[image: 1]

I've making it like this
[image]

as you can see ,

when I scroll up , gif list hide under SliverPersistentHeader
so pictures are not full size

this is I wanna fix it
I wanna prevent hiding  under tabbar in SliverPersistentHeader like tiktok profile screen

here's my code

```
SliverPersistentHeader(
  floating: false,
  pinned: true,
  delegate: _SliverAppBarDelegate(
    TabBar(
      indicatorColor: Constants.kPrimaryOrange,
      labelColor: Colors.black87,
      unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
      tabs: [
        Tab(text: "비디오"),
        Tab(text: "이미지"),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),


body: TabBarView(
  children: [
    /// gif Loading 
    Container( 
    ),
    /// image Loading 
    Container(
    ),
  ],
),


class _SliverAppBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  _SliverAppBarDelegate(this._tabBar);

  final TabBar _tabBar;

  @override
  double get minExtent => _tabBar.preferredSize.height;
  @override
  double get maxExtent => _tabBar.preferredSize.height;

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return new Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: _tabBar,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(_SliverAppBarDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide solution if you find?